# regex runs too slow

Tags: c#, regex

I have this code, but it bottlenecks all the code.
Any idea how to rewrite this to be more efficient?

```
Regex.Replace(text, @".+[a-zA-Z0-9]{17,500}.+(\r\n)", Environment.NewLine, RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Edit: Also, what’s your programming language?

Comment: Can you show us all the code?

Comment: What is `text`? Some file contents? Read line by line (or just split with a line break if you have a multiline string instead), and check each line with `Regex.IsMatch(line, "[a-zA-Z0-9]{17,500}")`. Upon a match, skip the line, else, append to the output. When you ask about efficiency, just a regex in the post is not enough. Please provide some more details.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, sounds like a game-plan. Please post as answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.+[a-zA-Z0-9]{17,500}.+(\r\n)` pattern is very inefficient due to the first `.+` subpattern that grabs the whole line at once and then backtracks to accommodate for the string of 17 (yes, 17 chars are checked and then the regex engine calls it a day) alphanumeric chars. This is a costly operation.

You should reconsider the approach. Instead of using `Regex.Replace` either split the text (if you have a big multiline string) with a line break to get an array of lines, or - if you are reading from a file - read it line by line, and check each string (item inside a list/array or the line) with a simple

```
Regex.IsMatch(line, "[a-zA-Z0-9]{17}")
```

to only check for 17 consecutive ASCII alphanumeric chars or - to really impose the limit of 17 to 500 such chars:

```
Regex.IsMatch(line, @"(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{17,500}(?![a-zA-Z0-9])")
```

If the match is found, skip the item/line, else, add it to the output/resulting array that you will later `string.Join("\n", resulting_list)`.

The `(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])` makes sure the preceding char is not an ASCII alphanumeric char and `(?![a-zA-Z0-9])` makes the same check for the following char.

Comment: I can confirm an improvement in performance. It is down from relative 50% to 1%.